# CSS. прописывание элемента внутри класса

Tags: css

Видел в одном видеоуроке, как парень прописывает код класса внутри другого класса.

Что-то на подобии такого:

```
.class1{
  height: 200px;
  ...
   h1 {
       color: black;
   }
   ...
}
```

Как это правильно прописывать? И как называется такой вид написания CSS?

HTML:

```
<div class="class1">
   <h1>here</h1>
</div
```

Answer (score 3):

Делается это только через препроцессоры. Почитайте про LESS, SASS, SCSS и т.д.

Код, который Вы указали, браузеры воспринимать не будут. Препроцессоры компилируют

```
.class1{
  height: 200px;      
   h1 {
       color: black;
   }      
}
```

в

```
.class1{
  height: 200px;           
} 
.class1 h1 {
  color: black;
}
```

Что очень удобно. Советую так же почитать про сборщики проектов: gulp, webpack и т.д.

Comment: А что лучше использовать (для скорости загрузки страницы)? SCSS или CSS?

Comment: В корне неправильный вопрос :) Вы не сможете использовать SCSS в продакшене, когда выкладываете файлы стилей на "рабочий" сервер. SCSS - препроцессор, на SCSS Вы пишете стили, которые в последствии будут преобразованы в CSS файл. Советую почитать вот это: https://mrmlnc.gitbooks.io/less-guidebook-for-beginners/content/chapter_1/css-reprocessors.html

Answer (score 1):

Речь о препроцессорах. Например в SCSS это может выглядеть так:

```
.class {
  color: black;
  &:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

После компиляции получится такой CSS:

```
 .class { color: black;}
 .class:hover { color: red;}
```

Препроцессоров много и функций у них гораздо больше.